# Im unable to receive postData of serializeEditData at server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm trying to send post data to server side using serializeEditData. However I only receive null of objects at server side.

I must be doing something wrong here.

Following is my code.

```
"url": paramsFromView.EditUrl,
"serializeEditData": function (postdata) {
     var rowId = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
     if (rowId != postdata.id) {
         alert("Invalid record selected.");
         return false;
      }
      var data = {
          Value1: $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('getCell', postdata.id, 'Value1'),
          Value2: postdata.Value2== '' ? null : postdata.Value2,
          Value3: postdata.Value3== '' ? null : postdata.Value3,
          Value4: $('#Value4').val()
      };
      // data contains all expected values here.
      return JSON.stringify(data);
},

Post URL: "http://localhost:53403/Controller/type/SomeAction/id"
Fomm Data: {"Value1":"18693","Value2":"1","Value3":"cc","Value4":"2"}: 

public JsonResult SomeAction(int type, int id, Information model)
{
      type // I receive the expected value.
      id  // I receive the expected value.
      model.Value1 // null
      model.Value2 // null
      model.Value3 // null
      model.Value4  // null
}

[Serializable]
public class Information
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }

    public decimal? Value2 { get; set; }

    public int Value3 { get; set; }

    public string Value4  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like pure binding problem on ASP.NET MVC side. The solution could depend on version of ASP.NET MVC, which you use. Replacement of `SomeAction` parameters to `int type, int id, string Value1, string Value2, string Value3, string Value4` or to `int type, int id, [FromBody] string model` should work. JSON string `model` will be needed to convert to `Information` manually. You can try to use `[FromBody] Information model`, but it will not work with old versions of .net

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thank you for your help as always. It's a binding problem because I can see values exist at Request.Form. However I still cannot receive them at the model parameter even with [FromBody]. I'm using asp.net mvc 4, .net 4.5 and VS 2017. I edited my question to include the model.

Comment: I even tried return $.extend(true, {}, { model: data  }) by manually converting the values at client side. but it seems I still get string objects at server side.

Comment: same code works in jqGrid 4.15.4-pre but I'm using jqGrid  4.6.0. upgrading is not an option at this moment.

Comment: It should be no difference in the case between free jqGrid 4.15.4 and  jqGrid 4.6.0 because both will send **the same data** `{"Value1":"18693","Value2":"1","Value3":"cc","Value4":"2"}`. You should solve the problem in your server code only.

Comment: that's strange, in my other project I'm using  jqGrid 4.15.4-pre and asp.net MVC 5, it works.

Comment: I's what I mean. The exact information about asp.net MVC, dependent products and so on could be important. You wrote that the problem exist in asp.net mvc 4 and seems not exist in asp.net MVC 5. Is it so or you use different NuGet packages additionally?

Comment: I don't think I use a different NuGet package related to this problem. I understand what you meant, I think the best way to change my parameters. string value1, value2, etc...?